# How can I apply a time zone to a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query who gives me the starting date and ending date of "last week".

```
to_char(trunc(sysdate-7, 'iw'),'YYYY-MM-DD')  as week_start,
to_char(trunc(sysdate-7, 'iw') + interval '6' day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as week_end,
```

I need to use the "at time zone 'US/Eastern'", but I don't succeed.
Thank you

Comment: Naive question:  is  "at time zone 'US/Eastern'" a literal that will always be used, or does this need to be calculated accordingly, per row?  This might require two totally different solutions.

Comment: I have to apply it to both lines, but it will be the same way.

Comment: Given that both of those expressions return a `date` where the time component is midnight, what does it mean to you to "apply a time zone"?  How do you expect the result to change?  Are you, for example, trying to return a `timestamp with time zone` rather than a `date` that matches the day and time from the current query and just adds in an explicit time zone?

Comment: Yes, I need something similar to this that I already use in that query:
to_char(cast(t.actual_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH24:MI') started,

Comment: Sample data and desired result would go a long way here.

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can use [FROM_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm#SQLRF00644):

```
FROM_TZ(sysdate, 'US/Eastern')
```

`FROM_TZ` accepts only a `TIMESTAMP` value, so you must use

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'US/Eastern')
```

However, the result will be correct only if the time zone of your database server's operating system is actually 'US/Eastern'. If you run `CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then Oracle takes your current `SESSIONTIMEZONE` which might be different to the time zone of your database server's operating system.

There is a much simpler solution, just use:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern'
```